# SFTP support in Lambda with Python

Tags: python, lambda, sftp

I am trying to SFTP a file from python lambda function to my server. But I am facing multiple issues with no idea on how to resolve those. 
Initially, I got the following error - "No hostkey for host" 
A quick google search suggested to use the following piece of code to stop the private key checks

```
cnopts = pysftp.CnOpts()
cnopts.hostkeys = None
with pysftp.Connection(host=server, username=username,password=password) as sftp:
```

This worked on my local machine, however when I deployed the code to Lambda, I got the following error.

```
    File "/var/task/handler.py", line 16, in upload_pic_and_return_url
with pysftp.Connection(host=server, username=username, password=password, cnopts=cnopts) as sftp:
File "/var/task/pysftp/__init__.py", line 143, in __init__
self._transport.connect(**self._tconnect)
File "/var/task/paramiko/transport.py", line 1086, in connect
self.start_client()
File "/var/task/paramiko/transport.py", line 500, in start_client
raise e
ImportError: cannot import name certificate_transparency
```

How can I resolve the Private key issue without adding cnopts or how can I use cnopts in lambda without error ?

Comment: Setting `cnopts.hostkeys = None` is not a solution. You are losing security by doing so!

Comment: Show us pysftp log file.